# Proof that the following Transcendental Equation has a Solution

Tags: calculus

I found the solution for the following transcendental equation, but I am having a hard time proving that this solution exists.

x^2 + cos(x) = -3

I don't have much experience with proofs, so how do we prove this?

Here is the graph:

[image]

Comment: The solution does not exist. $x^2 \ge 0 $, and $-1\le \cos(x) \le 1$, so the value $-3$ is unattainable for a real value of $x$.

Comment: solution using graphs is estimated to -2<x<-1.5

Comment: Are you confusing $x^2$ and $2x$?  The equation $2x+\cos (x)=-3$ has a [solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2x%2Bcos%28x%29%3D-3) near $x=-1.52$

Answer (score 1):

To prove that a solution exists, one technique is to find points where the function is positive and negative.  Then if the function is continuous, there must be (at least) a root in the interval.  Taking $f(x)=2x+\cos(x)+3$, we find $f(0)=4, f(-2)=-4+\cos(-2)+3 \lt 0$, so there must be a root in $(-2,0)$